# e.$OneSignal.on is not a function for Nuxtjs PWA - OneSignal

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps, onesignal

I'm using **@nuxtjs/pwa** along with **@nuxtjs/onesignal**.
I'm having an issue with listener to the **subscriptionChange** event on mounted.
It's working very well with **localhost**,
the issue is happened on **production**.

```
mounted() {
  let self = this;
  this.$OneSignal.push(() => {
  self.$OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', (isSubscribed) => {
    if (isSubscribed) {
      self.$OneSignal.getUserId().then((deviceId) => {
        self.addDeviceId(deviceId)
      });
     }
    });
  });
}
```

**On production error:**
[image]

Thank you and appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.OneSignal = window.OneSignal || []
    window.OneSignal.push(() => {
      window.OneSignal.getUserId(async (userId) => {
        await this.$store.dispatch(
          'Authenticated/overview/updatePushID',
          userId
        )
      })
    })
```

This work for me though both locally and on production

Comment: window.OneSignal = window.OneSignal || []
    window.OneSignal.push(() => {
      window.OneSignal.getUserId(userId => {
        console.log(userId)
      })
    })
  }

I've consoled:
-- Locally, I can see userId
-- Production, userId is Null

Comment: check your one signal config i think you need to make your one signal config match your url else user_id will always be null

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, I had these issues some hours back you need to access Onesignal using the global window method

```
window.OneSignal = window.OneSignal || []
window.OneSignal.push(() => {
  window.OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', (isSubscribed) => {
    if (isSubscribed) {
      window.OneSignal.getUserId().then((deviceId) => {
        self.addDeviceId(deviceId)
      });
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Hi brother, I've copied yours.
It's also work on local.
And now on production it's not error any more but Won't send playerId to OneSignal, it seems not work. ;(